# How to get last number from string like 12345678910111213 (numbers from 1 to 13 without any space in between)

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a String output like  12345678910111213 from a method  (numbers from 1 to 13 without any space in between) I want to get the last number from this series, In this case i need number 13 as output in order to use that with another method.

Can anyone help me in writing java code for the above logic?

Thanks in Adavance!!

Comment: Have you tried using substring to extract the last 2 characters?

Comment: Are numbers always going to be ordered integers starting from 1?

Comment: Last number is always 2 digits number or it can be in a range 1-9 ?

Answer (score 2):

If the numbers will always be ordered integers starting from 1 then you can try the following (highly inefficient) approach

```
public int getLast(String in) {
    int current = 0;
    while (in.length() != 0) {
        current++;
        in = in.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(current), "");
    }
    return current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simple answer is: you can't.

What you MIGHT want to do, if you have control on the string structure, is to pad each number with a zero (or zeros, if relevant), and then you can split the string into pairs (or trios, again, if relevant), and get the last group.

For example, instead of `12345678910111213` you would have `"010203040506070809010111213"`, and then you can break it into `"01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13"` - which is then easy to get your `"13"` out of.

Answer (score 0):

Do you always want to read the number using the last 2 characters? If not how can you know how many characters you want in your number?

```
int desiredNumberLength = 2;
String str = "12345678910111213";
int number = Integer.parseInt( str.substring( str.length - desiredNumberLength, str.length ) );
if ( number > 13 ) number = number % 10;
```

Comment: it can also also return 14 depending on the input

Comment: You'r right, didn't noticed it should be max 13... Edited the code, but still there is an unsolvable problem because he can't distinguish between "13" and "1"+"3"

Comment: @nafas sorry... I didn't checked your answer before posting and it really looks the same :)

Comment: that is true, the question is ambiguous, however I believe answer by @nomis is pointing the initial question.

Comment: its fine mate, as I said our answers are probably wrong. due to lack of clarity in the question.

Answer (score 0):

just split the last two numbers if greater than 13 then return last char otherwise return last two characters.
e.g.:

```
public int getLastNum(String numbers) throws Exception{
  if(numbers.length()==0) return 0;
  if(numbers.length()==1) return Integer.parseInt(numbers);
  int num=Integer.parseInt(numbers.subString(numbers.length-2,numbers.length));
  if(num>13) return num%10;
  else return num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline of an *algorithm*, the *assumption* is that the last number you want is a valid number up to and including `13`.

1. Read a character, if it's `1`, then (potentially could be 10/11/12/13), go to 2.
2. Read next character, if it's not `0|1|2|3`, then track the *value* of character in 1 as the `last_value`, then go to 4, else go to 3
3. Track the *value* of the characters collected in 1 & 2 as the `last_value` (so for example, characters `1` & `1`, would end up saving `11` in `last_value`.
4. If there are more characters, go to 1, else return the `last_value`.

Answer (score 0):

If you known the input is always well-formed with `1`, `2`, ..., `9`, `10`, `11`, `12`, …, `99` concatenated you can derive the last value simply by looking at the string length:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getLastNumber("123")); // 3
        System.out.println(getLastNumber("12345678910111213")); // 13
}

public static int getLastNumber(String input) {
        if (input == null) {
                return 0;
        } else if (input.length() > 9) {
                return 9 + ((input.length() - 9) / 2);
        } else {
                return input.length();
        }
}
```

For values larger than 99, the algorithm would need to be expanded (there surely is a generic solution to this problem that deals with arbitrarily large numbers…).